# Laravel Associate with relationship and create if not exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi I am new laravel and struggling a bit on understanding how to create relationships. I am trying to make a basic restful api in laravel and have 3 models

```
class Book extends Model {
   public function author()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
   }

   public function categories()
   {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_book')
        ->withTimestamps();
   }

}

class Author extends Model
{
    public function books(){
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book', 'category_book')
           ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Table migrations:

```
Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('ISBN', 32);
    $table->string('title');
    $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned();
    $table->float('price')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('surname');
    $table->timestamps();
});

  Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
}); 

Schema::create('category_book', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    //$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('book_id')->unsigned();
    //$table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')->on('books')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

books is the main table and author has a one to many relationships with books. Category has a many to many relationship with books as a book can be in more than one category.

The books table has an author_id field to link it to the author's table. There is also a pivot table called category_books that contains category_id and book_id to link books to categories.

Say I want to create a new book record and if the author exists to associate the book to that author but it if doesn't exist I want to create a new author record and then associate the book to that author?

I would also like to be able to do the same thing with categories

I have the following in my bookscontroller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $book = new book;
        $book->title = $request->title;
        $book->ISBN = $request->ISBN;
        $book->price = $request->price;
        $book->categories()->associate($request->category);
        $book->save();

        return response()->json($book, 201);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, in the line

```php
$book->categories()->associate($request->category);
```

The method `associate()` is used when you want to update a `belongsTo` relationship. 
$book->categories() is a many-to-many relationship (`belongsToMany`) so you should use `attach()` instead.

Secondly, if you want to associate an author that may or not exist, you can use the `firstOrCreate` method.

```php
$author = Author::firstOrCreate([
    'name' => $request->author_name,
    'surname' => $request->author_surname
]);
$book->author()->associate($author);
```

You can do the same with Categories, or Books for that matter.

```php
$category = Category::firstOrCreate([
    'name' => $request->category_name
]);
$book->categories()->attach($category);
```

```php
$book = Book::firstOrCreate([
    'ISBN' => $request->book_isbn,
    'title' => $request->book_title,
    'price' => $request->book_price
]);
$category->books()->attach($book);
```

The use of `firstOrCreate()` is documented here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods
This page has more on Eloquent relationship methods
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships